# C++ how to search in a 2D map

Tags: c++, search, maps

I do have `std::map <string, std::map <string, double> > myMap` and I want to search it with something like deapth-first search algorithm. The idea is to iterate over the "outer map" and their "inner maps". Then I want to use every found "inner string" and search for it in the "outer map" and search for the "inner string" in the "outer map" again and so on (like some kind of chain search). It is kind of hard for me to explain, so if anyone would like a picture in order to better understand this - no problem at all. Here is the code:

```
 string cmp;
 double rate,test, finalRate=1;
 for(auto & outer_map_pair : myMap) { // iterating over outer map
   rate = 1;
   for(auto & inner_map_pair : outer_map_pair.second) { // iterating over inner map
     cmp = inner_map_pair.first; // saving the inner string
     while(myMap.find(cmp) != myMap.end()){ // looking for inner string in outer map
       auto & arb_it = myMap.at(cmp).begin; //trying to look for inner string again - doesn't work
       test = my_it.second;
       finalRate *= test; // when this is above 1, I can exit the cyclus
     }
   }
 }
```

My main problem right now is the line `auto & arb_it = myMap.at(cmp).begin` - as I dont know how to access first "inner map" when I have found the corresponding outer map.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve logarithmically/logically? What is the meaning/significance/difference of the two `string`s per `double`? Why can't you use a `map<pair<string,string>,double>`? Perhaps you can provide examples of a typical situation and its desired outcome.

Comment: Yes, of course. It is supposed to be something like fictional currency exchange rate database, for example - USD -> EUR : 0.9259, where USD will be the first map and the pair EUR and the rate will be the second map's string and double. And the outcome should be whether you can make money from various transactions (when there are more transactions which can lead to profit in the end, not just this one).

Comment: A depth-first search of all possible closed loops will probably occupy your computer until the human race stops using money. Are the exchange rates reversible (that is, can I convert USD and EUR back and forth without loss)? And is the graph complete (that is, is there an exchange rate for every pair of currencies)? If either of these is true, then you can simplify this problem quite a lot.

Comment: No, they are not reversible. And there is one more condition - I can quit the search when the double meets certain conditions (I will edit the code so you can see it - at least a bit). And it doesn't have to be complete. Each time we are given a set of them and we have to decide.